# Why does this not display the current song image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get the image from the song album to display in the window with the song title and artist but it just doesn't do anything. I've tried replacing the "imageLabel" with

"imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window,image=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="CurrentSong.jpg"))" but it still doesn't work.

```py
import requests
import time
import tkinter

token = ''
endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"
spotifyHeaders = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}
requestAmount = 1
window = tkinter.Tk(className="|CurrentSong Spotify Song|")
window.geometry('400x400')
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window,height=1000,width=1000)
canvas.pack()
songLabel = tkinter.Label(window,bg='grey')
songLabel.pack()


def GrabSpotifyCurSong(curSongJson):
    return curSongJson['item']['name']
def GrabSpotifyCurArtist(curSongJson):
    return curSongJson['item']['artists'][0]['name']
def GrabCurrentSongImage(curSongJson):
    return curSongJson['item']['album']['images'][0]['url']
    
def displaySongs():
    while True:
        try:
            curSong = requests.get(endpoint, headers=spotifyHeaders)
            curSongJson = curSong.json()
            break
        except:
            print("Please start listening to a song")
            time.sleep(2)
    with open('CurrentSong.png','wb+') as SongImage:
        response = requests.get(GrabCurrentSongImage(curSongJson))
        SongImage.write(response.content)
    currentSong = GrabSpotifyCurSong(curSongJson)
    currentArtist = GrabSpotifyCurArtist(curSongJson)
    img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="CurrentSong.png")
    imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window,image=img)
    # songLabel['text'] = f'{currentArtist} - {currentSong}'
    # songLabel.place(height=400,width=400)
    print(f'{currentArtist} - {currentSong}')
    window.after(2500,displaySongs)

displaySongs()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "_it still doesn't work._" mean

Comment: @CoolCloud So "imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window,image=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="CurrentSong.jpg"))" gives me an error that says: "couldn't recognize data in image file "CurrentSong.jpg"" and the other one which is in the code just doesn't do anything

Comment: You can load the image data directly: `response = requests.get(GrabCurrentSongImage(curSongJson))`, `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=response.content)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images with `tkinter` has to be `PhotoImage` instances, here it is just a string of location of the image and `tkinter` does not understand that. Furthermore, `tkinter.PhotoImage` does not recognize JPEG format, so you have to convert it to PNG or use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` to use JPEG.

- For JPEG and other formats too:

  First `pip install Pillow` and then:

  ```
  import tkinter
  from PIL import Image, ImageTk

  ....
  img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CurrentSong.jpg"))
  imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window,image=img)
  ```

  Adding further here, you can also use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="CurrentSong.jpg")` but that will remove the flexibility that you could get if you want to, say, resize or do some filters to your image. If not, then use that.
- For GIF, PGM, PPM, and PNG:

  ```
  img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="CurrentSong.png")
  imageLabel = tkinter.Label(window,image=img)
  ```

---

Also note that if these are inside function you have to keep reference to the object to avoid it being collected by the `gc` after the function finishes running.

Comment: I copied what you put and I ran it(also removed the other labels just so they wouldn't go over the image just in case) and the same thing is happening where no image gets put into the window.

Comment: @Gravity Other labels won't go over the image, and also do you get any error?

Comment: no error, I will turn the image into a png and do it the way I was originally, and see if that works

Comment: and now I am getting the same error as before "couldn't recognize data in image file "CurrentSong.png""

Comment: @Gravity I don't think it will, because there is some mistake in your implementation. Edit your question with the updated code.

Comment: @Gravity To convert an image to PNG, you have to use a converting tool, not just change its filename from .jpeg to .png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233345/discussion-between-gravity-and-cool-cloud).